# Apache Camel 2.x and Servicemix 3.x/4

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I'm trying to run Camel 2.1 SU with Servicemix. As i understand there are no way to run Camel 2 with Servicemix 3, and i'm try to run it with FUSE Servicemix 4.0.0.1

When i starting my project with maven: `mvn jbi:servicemix` i receive following error:

```
unexpected element (uri:"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring", local:"camelContext"). Expected elements are <{http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring}aggregator>
```

That means that my `camel-context.xml` was parsed by Camel 1.x

Is there any way to use my, provided with SA/SU, version of Camel? Yes, i know that I can download Servicemix, remove existing Camel 1.x, and place there my version, but I don't want that hacks :( I need to run this using `mvn jbi:servicemix` command only

You can view all sources (poms, etc) of this project at http://github.com/splix/smx-currency-rates/tree/skeleton

Answer (score 3):

splix, I am using Camel 2.1 with SMX 3.3.1...its been working great so far.

Here are the steps...

1. get the source source from SVN (I used the latest as of 12/14/09)

   http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/servicemix/components/engines/servicemix-camel/trunk
2. build it - mvn clean install
3. copy the ./target/servicemix-camel-2009.02-SNAPSHOT-installer.zip file to your /servicemix/hotdeploy directory (also remove the old servicemix-camel-*.zip file)
4. then do a clean restart of servicemix and you should be up and running...

See this thread for more details...

http://old.nabble.com/Camel-2.1-with-Servicemix-3.3.1-td26718645ef12049.html#a26781927

Comment: I've got a question for Your setup - it's certainly nice to have camel 2.x running with smx3. But in my situation I need to have both camel 1.x and camel 2.x running - due to some compatibility issues. 

Have you done something like this? Have you run both versions on the same instance? I was thinking about renaming the other component to servicemix-camel-2. 

Maybe you have some clues?

Comment: nope, I didn't try to run both in parallel.  I just upgraded and had only minor changes necessary (up to v2.3 now).  Its a vast improvement over 1.x and worth any migration effort in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of servicemix-camel su are you using? 2009.01 version works only with camel 1.6. You can use camel 2.1-SNAPSHOT using the servicemix-camel 2009.02-SNAPSHOT version.